# How exactly do I use the GeoDjango Union function?

Tags: geodjango, union, django

I have two models in my application:

```
class Organization(models.Model):
    consortium = models.ForeignKey('Consortium')
    org_map = models.MultiPolygonField()

class Consortium(models.Model):
    cons_map = models.MultiPolygonField()
```

I'm trying to write some code that will union all the org_maps for organizations in a consortium, but am having trouble.

[The documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/gis/functions/#django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions.Union) leads me to believe that this is possible, I'm just a little off.

What I have so far is this:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db.models import functions as geodjango_functions

for consortium in Consortium.objects.all():
    for organization in Organization.objects.filter(consortium=consortium):
        if not consortium.cons_map:
            cons_map = organization.org_map
        else:
            union = geodjang_functions.Union(consortium.cons_map, organization.org_map)
            consortium.cons_map = union.geo_field
            consortium.save()
```

Unfortunately, this does not seem to work. Running the code doesn't produce any errors, but the resulting `cons_map` is always just the `org_map` for the last organization in that consortium. Any pointers about what exactly I'm doing wrong would be wonderful.

Answer (score 3):

Union is an [aggregate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/aggregation/) function. In this case you would use it like this:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db.models.aggregates import Union


for consortium in Consortium.objects.all():
    geom_union = Organization.objects.filter(consortium=consortium).aggregate(union=Union('org_map'))
    consortium.cons_map = geom_union["union"]
    consortium.save()
```